# why my ArrayList is not populating in struts (1.3)

Tags: java, arraylist, struts

My ActionForm has the following field.

```
//form
private ArrayList<String> chargeIds = new ArrayList<String>();  
public ArrayList<String> getChargeIds() {  
    return chargeIds;  
}  
public void setChargeIds(ArrayList<String> chargeIds) {  
    this.chargeIds = chargeIds;  
}//form
```

And in my jsp I wrote like below:-

```
//jsp
.... 

    <html:form action="/PurchaseOrderAction" styleId="defaultForm">
    <table> 
    <logic:iterate id="element" name="<%= Constants.SHOPPING_ORDER_CART_ITEMS %>" type="mypackage.ItemBean" >
    <tr><td>
     <logic:Equal name="element" property="promotedItem" value="true">
           <html:select property="chargeIds" styleClass="transperentList" indexed="true">
               <html:options collection="<%=Constants.ALL_CHARGES %>" property="key" labelProperty="name" />
        </html:select>
      </logic:Equal>
    <logic:notEqual name="element" property="promotedItem" value="true">
      <bean:write name="element" property="chargeName"/>
    </logic:notEqual>
    </tr></td>

.....
//jsp
```

I am getting jsp populated properly... but when i Submit the form.. i am not getting any value in the arraylist of my formbean.

any idea how? I am using struts 1.3 (unfortunately not able to update, as the project started from very long back, and i am a new member of the team).

### Thanks.

Sarjith

Comment: can you show the codes for servlet `/PurchaseOrderAction`?

Comment: I created my ActionClass by extending DispatchAction

So as per the parameter it will come to createInvoice() method of my action class. that method look like as follows:-


ActionForward fwd = init(mapping, form, request, response);
if (fwd != null)
  return fwd;
DefaultForm df = (DefaultForm) form;
CheckoutBean bean = (CheckoutBean) df.getBean();
.....

i put a debug on last line here, and chacked values in the variable "df". but its arraylist was empty.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow ... 
is my question clear enough?
Any idea why this doesnt work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to show a drop down list where only one option can be chosen? Or are you trying to show a multi select list where one or more than one option can be chosen?

Comment: @CarlosPastor I am trying to show a drop down list where only one option can be chosen. and i should get the value in the actionform, when the user click on submit.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `ArrayList` to `String[]` in your form object.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey .. I tried these also. that also dint work.
to my excitement, it works if i set any value from the action class.
(ie, if i want to have a default value selected - but that is not my case).

Comment: Now i worked with String[].
I just removed attribute _indexed="true"_ from html:select tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but according to your answer if you only want to select one of the options, the property of the html:select should be a String object and not an Arraylist. So your HTML should look something like this:

```
<html:select property="selectedChargeId" styleClass="transperentList" indexed="true">
    <html:options collection="chargeIds" property="key" labelProperty="name" />
</html:select>
```

And then your form should have these variables (with their respective getters and setters):

```
private ArrayList<String> chargeIds;
private String selectedChargeId;
```

It always works for me, I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I treid this but It dint worked for me. moreover, I dint find how the atrributes `selectedChargeId` and `chargeIds` get connected to populate the values.